# add border-bottom to the li by jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">test one</li>
```

I only want to add the `border-bottom` to the third and sixth line? why the following code doesn't work?

```
$(li:lt(2,5)).css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`:lt()` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) takes *one* argument only (*what is less than 2 is also less than 5!*).

```
$('li:eq(2), li:eq(5)').css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
```

The above is *one* way to do it. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5EXhP/))

Alternatively, you could introduce a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5EXhP/2/)):

```
$('li').filter(function(index) {
    return index == 2 || index == 5;
}).css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
```

Comment: jensgram,if i want to add a width to the css? how to write the code?

Comment: $('li:eq(2), li:eq(5)').css('border-bottom','1px solid red','width','500px');

Comment: @runeveryday `$('li:eq(2), li:eq(5)').css({'border-bottom': '1px solid red', width: '500px'})`. This is the [`.css(map)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) variant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close you `a` tags and enclose selector in quotes. Also change selector a bit.

Final jQuery in my opinion looks like this:

```
$("li:eq(2), li:eq(5)").css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KVpts/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li:eq(2),li:eq(5)").css({'border-bottom':'1px solid red'});
```